# How to show the Availability group listener instead of the nodes?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, configuration, sql-server-2017, connectivity

I have just installed a sql server availability group, `always on`, with 2 servers,

`SQLPROD1_TS` and `SQLPROD2_TS`  as you can see on the picture below:

```
select distinct rcs.database_name,
ar.replica_server_name,
drs.synchronization_state_desc,
drs.synchronization_health_desc,
CASE rcs.is_failover_ready
WHEN 0 THEN 'Data Loss'
WHEN 1 THEN 'No Data Loss'
ELSE ''
END as FailoverReady

from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states drs

inner join sys.availability_replicas ar 
       on drs.replica_id = ar.replica_id
      and drs.group_id = ar.group_id

inner join sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states rcs 
        on drs.replica_id = rcs.replica_id

order by replica_server_name
```

[image]

the listener for the availability group is calle `SQLPROD_TS` as you can see on the picture below

```
select * from 
sys.availability_group_listener_ip_addresses

select * from 
sys.availability_group_listeners

select * from 
sys.dm_tcp_listener_states
```

[image]

all is good, however, when I ask people to connect to `SQLPROD_TS` when they browse the network they can only see the nodes of the cluster.

[image]

Is there a way I could make `sqlProd_ts` to show up on the picture above, instead of the nodes?

Comment: The network server enumeration relies on the datagram returned by SQL Server Browser services, which I don't believe is AG listener-aware.

Comment: I think I just agree, only thing is that I have never found this info in any docs. Same thing is the `WINS` that need to be set on each node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I could make sqlProd_ts to show up on the picture above, instead of the nodes?

No, much as [Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman) has said, the listener is *not* an instance of SQL Server and as such will not respond to browser interrogations. In fact, availability groups do not use the browser service.

If you want people to use the listener, tell them the listener name.